# Eliminar símbolo monetario de cantidad numérica en Tag Html Span con Jquery en Wordpress

Tags: jquery

estoy desarrollando un sitio wordpress que tiene un elemento que me coloca una cantidad monetaria con su simbolo de moneda. Necesito eliminar ese símbolo de moneda manteniendo la cantidad monetaria.

Aquí el HTML:

```
<a href="https://acme.com/carro/" class="jet-blocks-cart__heading-link" title="View your shopping cart">
    <span class="jet-blocks-cart__label">Carrito:</span>        
    <span class="jet-blocks-cart__total">
        <span class="jet-blocks-cart__total-val">$0.00</span>
    </span>
</a>
```

Necesito de este tag `<span class="jet-blocks-cart__total-val">$0.00</span>`  eliminar el simbolo de moneda "$".

Lo que he probado con JQuery pero no me funciona:

```
var z = $(".jet-blocks-cart__total-val").text().replace('$','');
```

Help me, no funciona el reemplazo.

Gracias,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenga buen hombre:

```html
<a href="https://acme.com/carro/" class="jet-blocks-cart__heading-link" title="View your shopping cart">
    <span class="jet-blocks-cart__label">Carrito:</span>
    <span class="jet-blocks-cart__total">
        <span class="jet-blocks-cart__total-val">$0.00</span>
    </span>
</a>
<script>
    function cambiarSimbolo() {
        var text = document.getElementsByClassName("jet-blocks-cart__total-val")[0];
        text.textContent = text.textContent.replace('$', '');
    }
    window.onload = cambiarSimbolo;
</script>
```

Comment: Gracias buen hombre. Funciono a la perfección.  100pts para tí!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

1. copiar desde los templates del plugin el archivo

`wp-content/plugins/jet-blocks/templates/jet-blocks-cart/global/cart-totals.php`

a la carpeta del theme/chid theme ( crear carpetas con mkdir -p ) como

`tutheme-child/jet-blocks/jet-blocks-cart/global/cart-totals.php`

2. editar el template cambiando `WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal()` por `WC()->cart->get_displayed_subtotal()`

```
<?php
/**
* Cart totals template
*/

$elementor    = Elementor\Plugin::instance();
$is_edit_mode = $elementor->editor->is_edit_mode();

if ( $is_edit_mode && ! wp_doing_ajax() ) {
  $totals = '';
} else {
  $totals = wp_kses_data( WC()->cart->get_displayed_subtotal() );
}

?>
<span class="jet-blocks-cart__total-val"><?php
echo $totals;
?></span>
```

de esta manera se imprime sólo el número y si cambia el signo monetario ( pesos, €uros, etc... ) no deja de funcionar el javascript.

**edit:**

Si se quiere ocultar el símbolo via CSS se puede usar el formateador de precios de woocommerce en el `echo`, algo así:

```
echo wc_price( $totals );
```

esto da como resultado un html al que se le puede dar un `display:none` sólo al símbolo de moneda.

```
<span class="jet-blocks-cart__total-val">
  <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
    <bdi>
      <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>43.20
    </bdi>
  </span>
</span>
```

css

```
.jet-blocks-cart__total-val .woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Gracias Alo. Opte por la respuesta de https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/159806/ismael-gomez, aqui mismo. Funciono y corrigio mi error y no tuve que modificar el template del Plugins. De todas formas agredecido.

Comment: el plugin marca ese html como fragmento de woocommerce por lo cual será refrescado via ajax en varias situaciones, te agrego la función de formateo de wc para que se pueda ocultar el currecy symbol por css  ( como hace el cart de elementor-pro y como seguramente en algún momento hará jet-blocks )

Comment: Ohh, Alo... Muchísimas gracias por la aclaración. Muy útil y explicativo.